# Write to a text file and make content immediately available (C++/CLI)

Tags: c++-cli, flush

I am writing a C++/CLI program using Visual Studio 2008 with .NET version 3.5.

This program receives data from a COM port. If the string received is not in certain format, the program will output an error message with the line to a log file.

One of the requirement is that  the computer operator may come in and check the log file.

Here is my program (sort of):

```
FileStream ^ fs = File::Create("erorr-log.txt");
StreamWriter ^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fs);

// while receiving data from COM port
// if data is not in expected format
sw->WriteLine("Error in received data");
sw->WriteLine(received_string_data_from_port);

sw->Flush();   
sw->Close();
```

After the execution of `Flush`, if I check the file size of log file, it remains the same. I cannot open it in Notepad neither.

After the execution of `Close`, the file size changes and can be open in Notepad.

*Question*: Why the content is ***not available*** after `Flush`? Shouldn't `Flush` immediately 'update' the file? As in the last line in `Log ()` in [How to: Open and Append to a Log File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: If I remember correctly, when you open a file for writing in Windows it's by default locked exclusively to your process. The `flush` call will write to disk, but the file is still not readable by others. It won't be until you you close the file. I have no idea how to open it in shared mode in C++CLI or .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 FileStream ^ fs = File::Create("erorr-log.txt");
```

File::Create() is a convenience method, it picks a lot of defaults to construct the FileStream.  Defaults that you don't like, it uses FileShare::None.  That's a very safe choice, nobody will see a partially written file.  But prevents anybody from accessing the file until it is closed.

The simple workaround here is to not use it at all.  But use the [StreamWriter(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor instead.  Which also picks defaults, but it uses FileShare::Read.  Which you like.  A more reasonable safe choice for that class since it writes text streams and automatically flushes, unlike a FileStream.